# Why does B Tree can decrease the number of IO

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, b-tree

I'm reading an article about why we need B-Tree. It's telling me that B-Tree can decrease the number of IO whereas other trees, such as Red-Black tree, can't. And the number of IO equals to the height of B-Tree.

Here is an example.

We are looking for the value `9`. With the B-Tree, there are three times of IO, but with the binary tree, there are maybe four times of IO.

[image]

[image]

Now I'm confused. Why can the B-Tree ensure that there are at most only three times of IO? In other words, who can ensure that the node 3 and the node 7 must be located at the same disk block? I've thought that the data structure of each node in a B-Tree may be an array so that they were sequential, and sequential data is normally located at the same disk block (seriously, I'm not sure...), but it seems that the data structure of the node in a B-Tree is a List, which means that they are not sequential. So as my understanding, it's also possible to generate two times of IO while accessing `3` and `7`. In this case, can't we say that accessing `9` may also need 4 times of IO?

Answer (score 0):

On disk, every B-tree node is in a single contiguous block, and every node contains *thousands* of keys.

For each key there is a pointer to the corresponding node in the next level.  On disk, this "pointer" is the address of the contiguous block that contains the target node.

So, for example, if there are 10^9 leaf-level keys, there could be 1000000 leaf-level nodes.  On the parent level, there are 1000000 keys that point to those nodes, distributed among 1000 parent nodes.  On the root level, there are 1000 keys in a single node.

Comment: Why is it "On disk"? How is it put on disk? You see, when we create some data structure, such as a binary tree, this data structure is located in RAM, instead of on disk.

Comment: It's "On disk", because you're asking about I/Os, and B-Trees are most commonly used for database indexes... on disk.  And, of course, because your question specifically mentions disk blocks.  Did you not even read what you wrote?

Comment: But how could you control the disk IO action? You see, as I said, we can create a binary tree and play in RAM, everything is in RAM, right? So how could B-Tree control the IO? For example, we are developing a new database and we want to use B-Tree, does it mean that we need to invoke some system calls while playing with B-Tree so that we can control the IO action?